# local WAMP admin user has lost privileges

Tags: admin

I have a Wordpress 3.4.1 installed on a local WAMP server.

I am in the process of upgrading it to a network, but I now realise my admin account has no admin privileges:

1. No access to the Updates page (update-core.php) - I receive "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."
2. No ability to install plugins.
3. No ability to edit users.
4. No ability to go to Tools > Network Setup - same error as above.

   - The **wp_capabilities** of my user account is **a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}**
   - The **wp_user_level** is **10**

What is wrong here?

**Update** - I added another admin account using PHPMyAdmin following [this tutorial](http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database), but I receive the same symptoms for this 2nd admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just done a new install of a newly download zip file, and the installation process stops at:

```
http://localhost/site/wp-admin/install.php?step=2
```

This page is blank, and nothing progresses.

I now recall this happened on my previous installation also.

If I refresh this page, I receive a message:
"Already Installed
You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first."

I can elect to log in from here, and doing so presents me with the ability to install Plugins, which I can't do on my other installation.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Folder Permissions problems - the MAMP Apache user needs to have read/write privileges on everything under your `Sites/wordpress/` folder.

This is easy to do from the terminal ... my post on Permissions should help
[can i run wp as root permissions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61608/can-i-run-wp-as-root-permissions/61614#61614)

Comment: Does your solution work in a Windows WAMP environment?

Comment: The solution applies to any server setup .. Linux, mac, windows. Folder permissions and ownership are crucial to making Wordpress work.

Comment: How do I know what user is running Wordpress?  Is it Apache?  There is no such user in the Windows OS.  Do I have to create a Windows user called Apache, and provide it with permissions to the Wordpress folder?

Comment: Hi ... WAMP creates a user called WAMPAPACHE. [This answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683766/is-it-possible-to-have-wamp-run-httpd-exe-as-user-myself-instead-of-local-syst) might help you to identify the user and change it to your name. Your 'wordpress' folders are probably owned by 'you' and 'wampapache' needs to have ownership of these.

Comment: There has been no new user account created on the computer after installing WAMP, and there is no user account with *wamp* in it.

Comment: I've never tried WAMP, but there are some instructions at httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html#winsvc. I think the part you're probably interested in starts with "By default, all Apache services are registered to run as the system"

Comment: And the System user account already has full read/write access to the Wordpress folder.